# Cannot determine default configuration path. No file [config.yml config.yaml] in cloudflared Linux

Tags: linux, yaml, tunnel

I am trying to make Argo tunnel work and I faced the problem with configuration files config.yml config.yam on the local host testing phase.

```
changerz_critical@cloudshell:~ (global-road-289110)$ /usr/local/bin/cloudflared --origincert /etc/cloudflared/cert.pem --no-autoupdate
INFO[2020-09-15T15:00:59Z] Cannot determine default configuration path. No file [config.yml config.yaml] in [~/.cloudflared ~/.cloudflare-warp ~/cloudflare-warp /etc/cloudflared /usr/local/etc/cloudflare
d]
INFO[2020-09-15T15:00:59Z] Version 2020.9.0
INFO[2020-09-15T15:00:59Z] GOOS: linux, GOVersion: go1.14.7, GoArch: amd64
```

I tried `$ cloudflared tunnel --config tunnels/config.yml` several times but there is no use of it (I tried to place config.yml in all the folders subsequently but Cloud Shell couldn’t find it. Could you please let me know what could help me to solve the problem?

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add `--url` before url as follow:

```
cloudflared tunnel --hostname {full hostname} --url http://localhost:8000
```